# after download .zip remotely where it will be store on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, download, nsurlconnection

if i am using NSURLConnection for file download remotely then  where it will be store on iphone and how user will open that downloaded file?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an NSURLConnection, it won't automatically get stored anywhere (except in the cache), you will need to save it to a location in your code.

The NSData you get from the NSURLConnection can be stored to a path this way:

`[data writeToPath:path atomically:NO];`. You'll need to find a path on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method to store the zip file as NSData.

You can then manipulate it in your code.

See the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection does not store data anywhere. It only downloads chunks. This is your responsibility to append that data during download and then store it wherever you want (and if you need).